# Difference between an org element and entry

Tags: org-mode

What are Org elements (e.g. `org-element-type`) and entries (e.g. `org-entry-get`)?

The best I can figure is that an entry is anything in the buffer.  Org defines properties (`org-special-properties` and `org-default-properties`) for various purposes; TODOs, clocks, etc.  The text in a buffer is parsed through string matching and properties are identified correspondingly.  So, an entry is text with (or representing) a property?

It also looks like there is a push for a fully parsed syntax tree, starting with (or around) Org 9.  The `org-element.el` library parses a buffer into an AST composed of elements.  Therefore, an element is merely a node in the abstract syntax tree?

Comment: For elements, see the description in the header comment of `org-element.el` and also the [API doc](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html) and the [syntax doc](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-syntax.html). Instead of "entry" you should probably read "property": the API is described [in the manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Property-API.html#Using-the-Property-API).